# Configuring SDK in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a problem getting my SDK to intelliJ idea, i have downloaded Java SE newest edition, and put it in a seperate folder on my desktop. Whenever i chose it from intellij it just shows an error, Anybody knows a fix?

[image]

Comment: What is in that folder? As the error tells you it is not the root folder of the actual JDK

Comment: I just downloaded the lastede Java SE SDk from oracle.com and placed all content in a seperate folder.

Comment: For Microsoft Windows Oracle only provides an installer - do you mean that you selected this directory as target when running the installer? In that case there's a folder called `jdk-X.X.X` (with `X` being some numbers) that you need to select instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have there really the JDK home. If you click to the arrow on the left of your `Java SE`, it should look something like this (my `jdk1.8.0_152` is the proper home folder of a JDK):

[image]

Also your `Java SE\bin` folder should contain the `javac.exe` file - notice the `c` at the end of the file name :)

I always download the full installer from Oracle (just search google for `oracle java SE JDK download`) and then run it. You may specify the destination folder where you want it to be installed, or you rather leave the default (I strongly recommend that).

[image]

Comment: Super cool! Thank you, did you just download the filedirectory from oracles website, or where did you get it? And did you extract the folder?